# Find value in the same row of another value that has been looked up?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, lookup, excel-365

I looked up values from another sheet with the following formula:

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Detail list'!$H$2:$H$1604;SMALL(IF(1=((--(A$1='Detail list'!$J$2:$J$1604))*(--(A$2='Detail list'!$I$2:$I$1604)));ROW('Detail list'!$H$2:$H$1604)-1;"");ROW()-2));"")`

This lookup is based on two criteria: Company name and year.

[image: Lookup example]

The lookup happens in cell A3 and onwards. It uses the company name in A1 and the year from A2 and then finds a corresponding value in another sheet. There's duplicates involved here since the column that is used for this look up consists only of 001 up til 010. It still is able to return all the values in the correct sequence based on year and company name.

I now want to look up or couple a 'corresponding' value with the value that was just acquired. For example: The value in A3 (005) refers to a specific cell in the other sheet. I want to return a value from that exact row but a different column. I have tried the following:

`=IFERROR(@INDEX('Detail list'!$B$2:$B$1604;AGGREGATE(15;6;(ROW('Detail list'!$H$2:$H$19883)-ROW('Detail list'!$H$1))/('Detail list'!$H$2:$H$19883=A3);COUNTIF($A$3:$A3;A3)));"")`

This does return a value (namely a client value) but this it is not precise as it takes the first 005 it comes across in the full list (so no longer sorted on year and company!) and reports that. I need it to be from the exact row the previous value is referring to.

I'd be so happy if anyone could help me out with this one. If not, I understand completely,

Kind regards,

VHes

Comment: Not sure I follow this. There is only one 005 in your list?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping references consistent and clear across sheets while nesting statements can be tricky. Have you considered pasting the data from 'Detail List' into your current sheet and using something like VLOOKUP or INDEX that way?

Another possible solution would be to throw everything into a pivot table and use the filters to get what you need. Not sure if either of these apply to your task.